# Angular project - wrong html file loaded

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning Angular. A [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-http-client?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I am trying to understand, the issue is around the flow of execution.

The app.component.ts contains:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
```

The my-app selector is only seen in the index.html file which has a single line:

```
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

Based on this I would expect to see a webpage containing the word "loading".

However the actual page I see looks more like app.component.html which gets data from an API and looks like :

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
{{this.products |json}}
```

[image]

So the question is why is the selector used in index.html, but the content displayed looks more like app.component.html?

The code snippets above are taken from [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-http-client?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 2):

The correct html file is being loaded. The way Angular works is that it uses the selector in index.html and renders the app in it.

The reason you aren't seeing the word Loading is that Angular components replace their contents. If you put anything inside any angular component, that content will be replaced when the component renders.

Normally, you can still access that content by using an `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag. The root module appears to be different. My guess is that's either because index.html isn't part of the same module, or because it's a root component, and root components don't have that feature.

If you make an application that is very big however, you will briefly see that loading text in the time between when your machine receives the index.html from the server, and the time it takes for the Angular application to finish bootstrapping after your browser loads the html file. The longer it takes for your application to load up, the longer that text will be visible for.